# How to speed up video conversion

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, server, avconv, zoneminder

I'm currently working in a project that involves converting large series of .jpg (>6000) into video format. These frames (320x240) are stored in folders at a rate of 2.5fps. Generating a couple of folders every hour that need to be converted ASAP.

For now I've tried copying the folder to a ram disk and using avconv which takes about a minute.

Here is my command:

```
avconv -threads auto -y -r 2.51 -i %03d-capture.jpg -s 320x240 -r 25 video.mpeg
```

- Could ffmpeg work faster?
- Is there a way to speed it up?
- Which video format takes less time to convert to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg with x264 should work faster.

```
ffmpeg -threads auto -y -framerate 2.51 -i %03d-capture.jpg -r 25 -preset ultrafast video.mp4
```

I've removed the size option, since if they don't need to be resized, you can save time by bypassing the scaler call.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it as soon as i get home!